# LDAP user authentication using nslcd on Debian 8.x

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, debian

I installed in Debian 8.5 the package **libpam-ldapd**, then I proceeded to configure the file **/etc/nslcd.conf** with the following configuration:

---

```
# /etc/nslcd.conf
# nslc

d configuration file. See nslcd.conf(5)
# for details.

# The user and group nslcd should run as.
uid nslcd
gid nslcd

# The location at which the LDAP server(s) should be reachable.
uri ldap://172.17.192.100

# The search base that will be used for all queries.
base DC=myorg,DC=com

# The LDAP protocol version to use.
ldap_version 3

binddn CN=ldapuser,DC=myorg,DC=com
bindpw secret

# The search scope.
#scope sub
filter passwd (objectClass=person)
map    passwd uid              sAMAccountName
map    passwd uidNumber        employeeID
map    passwd gidNumber        objectSid

filter shadow (objectClass=person)
map    shadow uid              sAMAccountName
```

---

Problem is that when logging into the server with user@myorg.com I have the following log (auth sucessfull but search fails due to the *@myorg.com* section, also it uses the nslcd_pam_authc() function ):

```
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.17.192.100)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_DEREF,0)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,0)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,0)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_set_option(LDAP_OPT_RESTART,LDAP_OPT_ON)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("CN=isldap,DC=TI,DC=ads","***") (uri="ldap://172.17.192.100")
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="DC=myorg,DC=com", filter="(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=user@myorg.com))")
nslcd: [8e1f29] <passwd="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
nslcd: [e87ccd] DEBUG: connection from pid=9046 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [e87ccd] <authc="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: nslcd_pam_authc("user@myorg.com","sshd","***")
nslcd: [e87ccd] <authc="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="DC=myorg,DC=com", filter="(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=user@myorg.com))")
nslcd: [e87ccd] <authc="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
nslcd: [e87ccd] <authc="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="DC=myorg,DC=com", filter="(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=user@myorg.com))")
nslcd: [e87ccd] <authc="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
nslcd: [e87ccd] <authc="user@myorg.com"> DEBUG: "user@myorg.com": user not found: No such object
```

---

If I login using only **user** the search has success but the authentication does not. (Tries to authenticate using full DN and ldap_sasl_bind() function)

```
nslcd: [8b4567] <host=10.0.2.2> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("CN=ldapuserDC=myorg,DC=com","***") (uri="ldap://172.17.192.100")
nslcd: [8b4567] <host=10.0.2.2> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
nslcd: [8b4567] <host=10.0.2.2> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="OU=Guatemala Support Team,OU=TI_Service_Accounts,DC=TI,DC=ads", filter="(&(objectClass=ipHost)(ipHostNumber=10.0.2.2))")
nslcd: [8b4567] <host=10.0.2.2> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
nslcd: [7b23c6] DEBUG: connection from pid=9099 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="DC=myorg,DC=com", filter="(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=user))")
nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.17.192.100)
nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("CN=ldapuser,DC=myorg,DC=com","***") (uri="ldap://172.17.192.100")
nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): CN=User John Doe,DC=myorg,DC=com
nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="user"> CN=User John Doe,DC=myorg,DC=com: objectSid: missing
nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="OU=Guatemala Support Team,OU=TI_Service_Accounts,DC=TI,DC=ads", filter="(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=user))")
nslcd: [7b23c6] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
nslcd: [3c9869] DEBUG: connection from pid=9099 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="DC=myorg,DC=com", filter="(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=user))")
nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): CN=User John Doe,DC=myorg,DC=com
nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="user"> CN=User John Doe,DC=myorg,DC=com: objectSid: missing
nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="OU=Guatemala Support Team,OU=TI_Service_Accounts,DC=TI,DC=ads", filter="(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=user))")
nslcd: [3c9869] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
nslcd: [334873] DEBUG: connection from pid=9099 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [334873] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="DC=myorg,DC=com", filter="(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=user))")
nslcd: [334873] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): CN=User John Doe,DC=myorg,DC=com
nslcd: [334873] <passwd="user"> CN=User John Doe,DC=myorg,DC=com: objectSid: missing
nslcd: [334873] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (1 total)
nslcd: [334873] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="OU=Guatemala Support Team,OU=TI_Service_Accounts,DC=TI,DC=ads", filter="(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=user))")
nslcd: [334873] <passwd="user"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): end of results (0 total)
nslcd: [b0dc51] DEBUG: connection from pid=9099 uid=0 gid=0
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: nslcd_pam_authc("user","sshd","***")
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="DC=myorg,DC=com", filter="(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=user))")
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.17.192.100)
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: ldap_simple_bind_s("CN=ldapuserDC=myorg,DC=com","***") (uri="ldap://172.17.192.100")
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): CN=User John Doe,DC=myorg,DC=com
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="CN=User John Doe,DC=myorg,DC=com", filter="(objectClass=*)")
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: ldap_initialize(ldap://172.17.192.100)
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: ldap_set_rebind_proc()
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: ldap_sasl_bind("CN=User John Doe,DC=myorg,DC=com","***") (uri="ldap://172.17.192.100")
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: ldap_parse_result() result: Invalid credentials: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903D0, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://172.17.192.100: Invalid credentials: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903D0, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: ldap_unbind()
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> CN=User John Doe,DC=myorg,DC=com: Invalid credentials
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: myldap_search(base="DC=myorg,DC=com", filter="(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=user))")
nslcd: [b0dc51] <authc="user"> DEBUG: ldap_result(): CN=User John Doe,DC=myorg,DC=com
```

---

Question: how should I configured nslcd.conf if I wanted to:

- Login with **user**
- Search in the sAMAccount field equal to **user**

Thank you in advance and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score -1):

In /etc/nslcd.conf, Try changing (objectClass=person) to

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))
```

-jim